# How to erase all Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm creating a Helper to find out if the user is using my app for the first time (not only), that's why I'm using Xamarin.Forms.Aplication.Current.Properties. When the user logs out, the app will remove all keys, include that. But this is not happening and I don't know what.

My code:

```
public static class FirstUseAppHelper
    {
        public static string FIRST_USE = "FirstUse";

        public static void Initialize()
        {
            if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey(FIRST_USE))
            {
                Application.Current.Properties[FIRST_USE] = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Current.Properties[FIRST_USE] = true;
            }
        }

        public static bool CheckFirstUseApp()
        {
            if (!Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey(FIRST_USE))
                throw new Exception("Key not found.");
            else
                return Application.Current.Properties[FIRST_USE].Equals(true);
        }
    }
```

When the app starts (App.Xaml.cs) is called the method:

```
protected override async void OnInitialized()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    FirstUseAppHelper.Initialize();
    ...
}
```

Logout method (This is not working):

```
LogOutCommand = new DelegateCommand(() =>
{
    var keys = Application.Current.Properties.Keys.ToList();

    foreach (var k in keys)
        Application.Current.Properties[k] = null;

    Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
}
```

I understand that the code is correct, but for some reason the keys are not being erased. Has anyone had this problem or has a better solution?

Comment: if you just need to know if this is the first run of your app, use Essentials Version Tracking - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/version-tracking

Comment: My mistake, my control is not the only one to check the first use in the APP, but the first use by modules.

Comment: You can print the Application.Current.Properties[FIRST_USE] at the LogOutCommand  to see if the keys are erased correctly.

Comment: Have you tried `Application.Current.Properties.Clear();` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the automatic backup of the latest versions of Android.
You need to add `android:allowBackup="false"` and `android:fullBackupContent="false"` to the   tag in AndroidManifest.xml
if you don't want to back up your data or if you want to include or exclude some features.